# Can I enforce use of DataContracts when creating a service end point from WSDL?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, datacontract

I am trying to create a WCF service client using VS 2010. The service itself is not WCF and I have no control over it. As the service uses polymorphic arrays in its responses, I must inject `KnownTypes` in my client. What I wanted to do is adding a `DataContractResolver` as described in
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx, but this does not work, because the classes generated in my client stub do not use `DataContract`s (my code is never called). Is there any possibility to enforce that? Or can I do something like the `DataContractResolver` on classes only that have the following attributes:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="...")]
```

Comment: I think this post answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034127/in-a-wcf-proxy-generated-client-what-determines-the-serializer-used